# Como fazer uma subtração de array

Tags: javascript, array

Supondo que tenho um array

```
let arr1 = [
     {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
     {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30}, 
     {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}
]
```

e tenho outro

```
let arr2 = [
         {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
         {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}, 
]
```

Como faço pra remover do `arr1` os objetos que sejam iguais ao do `arr2`.
Por exemplo, retornando assim um novo array:

```
let arr3 = [
             {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
             {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30}, 
             {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52} 
    ]
```

Comment: Seria um caso de subtração e não left join.

Comment: Exato:  subtrair um array do outro

Comment: Alterei o título, veja se está mais claro por favor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Crie um objeto `arr3` igual ao `arr1` e faça um loop no `arr2` verificando se existe no `arr1`. Caso exista, remova do `arr3` com `splice`. No final você terá um `arr3` sem os itens que tem no `arr2`:

```js
let arr1 = [
     {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
     {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30}, 
     {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}
]

let arr2 = [
   {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
   {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}
]

let arr3 = arr1;

for(let it2 in arr2){
   for(let it1 in arr1){
      if(JSON.stringify(arr2[it2]) == JSON.stringify(arr1[it1])){
         arr3.splice(it1, 1);
         break; // se achou, não precisa continuar o loop
      }
   }
}

console.log(arr3);
```

### Edit

Convertido os itens em string para comparação como um todo, e não por valores.

### Edit 2

Uma outra forma usando `filter`:

```js
let arr1 = [
     {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
     {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30}, 
     {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}
]

let arr2 = [
   {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
   {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}
]

const arr3 = arr1.filter( x => { 
  return JSON.stringify(arr2).indexOf(JSON.stringify(x)) < 0;
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Teria que comparar as duas propriedades, da forma que está ele só compara o nome logo se a idade for diferente não são iguais e mesmo assim o item será removido.

Comment: Funcionou, fiz somente uma alteração. No `if(it2.nome == it1.nome)` eu não posso somente comparar o nome, preciso comparar o objeto inteiro, então fiz `if(it2 == it1)`. É correto eu fazer isso?

Comment: Não irá funcionar porque são objetos diferentes. O que precisa comparar são valores. Fiz uma edição na resposta comparando os dois valores.

Comment: entendi, o problema, é que na minha situação real, o objeto contém muitos valores, mais de 10, e eu precisaria q todos fossem iguais pra ter certeza que aquele objeto seria igual ao do `arr1`, tem algum modo de identificar o objeto ao invés de ficar fazendo por exemplo: `it2.nome == it1.nome` ?

Comment: @LeonardoTheodoro pronto. Corrigido.

Comment: Perdão, mas eu ainda terei que usar o  `.nome` e o `.idade`?

Comment: @LeonardoTheodoro Converti para string com JSON.stringify, assim é possível verificar se tudo é igual.

Comment: Isso, era exatamente o que precisava, dessa forma funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr1 = [       
 {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19},         
 {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
 {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30},
 {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20},  
 {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}
];

let arr2 = [
  {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20},
  {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}
     
];

arr1 = arr1.filter( a1 => !arr2.filter( a2 => a1.nome == a2.nome).length);

console.log(arr1);
```

Explicação :

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

dentro do primeiro Array.filter ele chama outro Array.filter, para o array 2
dentro desse Array.filter (o segundo) ele verifica se existe o mesmo valor no array 2, então com o length vc pega o resultado do if que é 0 ou 1 então o ! no primeiro Array.filter so vai pegar se for 0, no caso se já existe o nome no array 2 então ele não vai pegar esse valor;

Comment: Só faltou uma breve explicação do funcionamento do `Array.filter` e a verificação da idade para ficar completo.

Comment: adicionei uma explicação.

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais rápida e simples é converter os objetos em uma string JSON, compara-las e realizar o filtro.

Porém se há outras necessidades como validar se todas os atributos e valores estão presentes nos dois lados e até em uma diferente ordem o algoritmo vai ficando cada vez mais elaborado. E eu não testei esse exemplo com objetos de maior complexidade.

Segue um exemplo.

```js
let arr1 = [       
     {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19},         
     {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
     {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30},
     {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20},  
     {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}
]

let arr2 = [
  {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20},
  {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}
         
]

var removerItems = function(arrayOriginal, arrayFiltrar) {
  var filtro = arrayOriginal.slice();  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayFiltrar.length; i++) {
    var itemBusca = arrayFiltrar[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < filtro.length; j++) {
      if (JSON.stringify(filtro[j]) === JSON.stringify(itemBusca)){
        filtro.splice(j,1);        
      }
    }    
  }
  
  return filtro;
}

console.log(removerItems(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método [`differenceWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#differenceWith) da biblioteca [Lodash](https://lodash.com).

```js
let arr1 = [
   {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
   {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 39}, 
   {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}, 
   {nome: 'João',   idade: 20}, 
   {nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30}, 
   {nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}
]

let arr2 = [
   {nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19}, 
   {nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}
]
let arr3 = _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, _.isEqual);
console.log(arr3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Criei uma função que recebe duas listas de objetos e uma propriedade, como ela funciona:

Para cada iteração da primeira lista eu percorro a segunda comparando a propriedade recebida, se essa propriedade não existir na segunda lista então eu adiciono em uma terceira lista que após todas as iterações será o retornada pela função.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function subtraiArray(arr1, arr2, prop){
  let arr3 = [];
  var existe;
  for(i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    existe = false;
    for(j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
      if(arr1[i][prop] == arr2[j][prop]){
        existe = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    //Caso o nome dessa posição não exista no segundo array eu insiro
    if(!existe)
      arr3.push(arr1[i]);
  }
  
  return arr3;
}

let arr1 = [{nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19},{nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20},{nome: 'João',   idade: 20},{nome: 'Maria',  idade: 30},{nome: 'Teste',  idade: 52}];

let arr2 = [{nome: 'Fulano', idade: 19},{nome: 'Ciclano',idade: 20}];

console.log(subtraiArray(arr1, arr2, "nome"));
```

Comment: E se há mais uma camada de objetos ou arrays dentro do elemento?

Comment: Posso fazer a função recebendo uma lista de propriedades ao invés de só uma propriedade ou mandar comparar todas, é que na pergunta dele não está explicito a necessidade de comparar por mais de uma propriedade.

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito mais simples de fazer é, primeiro, você deve achar o index do elemento que deseja remover:

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
```

Então pode removar o elemento, caso tenha sido encontrado, utilizando o método splice:

```
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

No seu caso, como é um array bidimensional você pode usar a seguinte função para obter o index ao percorrer o segundo array:

```
findIndex(x => x.nome == 'Ciclano')
```

Comment: Mas ai, você tem somente um array, no caso, de eu ter dois, eu preciso pegar o indexOf do `arr1` , eu precisaria saber o elemento igual no `arr2`

Comment: no `x.nome == 'Ciclano'` como seria feito pra comparar o objeto inteiro do `arr1` com o objeto inteiro do `arr2`?

Comment: só adicionar mais uma condição: findIndex(x => x.nome == 'Ciclano' && x.idade == 20).

Comment: Entendo, mas duas observações:
 1 - Você está usando valores fixos, a ideia é q ele compare com os valores do outro array. (que no caso pode variar)
 2 - Na minha situação real, são muitos valores, não somente nome e idade, então, é bem improvável que eu faça manualmente valor por valor

Comment: Ok, mas isso é só um exemplo. Você pode fazer uma iteração do array e pegar o valor dentro do for da seguinte forma: array[indexFor][nomeCampo]